# Translating R mutate conditional across two columns to Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr, translate

I am translating something in R to Python and can't understand how to implement a conditional mutate function across two columns to something comparable in Python.

```r
df <- df %>%
    select(col_1,…,col_n) %>%
    mutate(new_col = ifelse(is.na(col_1), NA, 2),
           new_col = ifelse(is.na(col_2), new_col, ifelse(col_3 == 1, new_col+1, new_col-1))).
```

So far, I have the below where col_1 is a string, col_2 is a string and col_3 is a float:

```py
df = df[[col_1,...,col_n]]
df[new_col] = df[col_1].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x is np.nan else 2)
```

And cannot figure out how to do the next mutation. I have tried the following:

```py
1. df[new_col] = df.apply[col_2](lambda x: x if x is ' ' else df[col_3].apply(lambda x: x+1 if x == 1 else x-1) 
# This timesout the kernel


2. df[new_col] = df.apply(lambda x: x if x[col_2] == ' ' else x+1 if x[col_3] == 1 else x-1 if x[col_3] != else x)
# This results in an error of unsuporrted operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
# I also don't think the 'else x' at the end is the correct way to get the same result
```

Is there either a way to do this through something less computationally expensive than the nested apply (if that's even a correct method of attack) or some way to extract the necessary information manually?

Comment: don't compara to "" use numpy, no need to use apply this is just a bunch of ifelses, please create a reprex

Comment: Kindly create sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the "literal" translation would be something like this:

```
df = df[[col_1,...,col_n]]
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col_1'].isnull(), 
                         np.nan, 
                         2)
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col_2'].isnull(), 
                         df['new_col'], 
                         np.where(df['col_3'] == 1, 
                                  df['new_col']+1, 
                                  df['new_col']-1))
```

Comment: Wow yea this did it!!! I guess I could have been using this method for the rest of the apply methods too. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi @donutpancake if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. 
Thank you!

Comment: Hi @LeonardoViotti Done! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also translate your R code into python with `datar` smoothly:

```py
>>> from datar.all import NA, f, tibble, select, mutate, if_else, is_na
>>> 
>>> df = tibble(
...     col_1 = [1, NA, 2, 3],
...     col_2 = [4, 5, NA, 7],
...     col_3 = [8, 9, 10, 1],
...     unk_col = list('abcd')
... )
>>> 
>>> df >> select(f.col_1, f.col_2, f.col_3) >> mutate(
...     new_col_ = if_else(is_na(f.col_1), NA, 2),
...     new_col = if_else(
...         is_na(f.col_2), 
...         f.new_col, 
...         if_else(f.col_3 == 1, f.new_col+1, f.new_col-1)
...     )
... )
      col_1     col_2   col_3   new_col
  <float64> <float64> <int64> <float64>
0       1.0       4.0       8       1.0
1       NaN       5.0       9       NaN
2       2.0       NaN      10       2.0
3       3.0       7.0       1       3.0
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.